# 'import feedparser' works via SSH, but fails when in browser

Tags: python, browser, feedparser, import

I installed feedparser via SSH, using

```
$ python setup.py install --home=~/httpdocs/python-libraries/feedparser-4.1/
```

I did that because I don't seem to have permission to properly run 'python setup.py install'

I am running the following python code in 'test.py'.

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
try:
    import feedparser
except:
    print "Cannot import feedparser.\n"
```

The code runs fine when I am logged in by SSH. But when I view it in a browser, it prints

`Cannot import feedparser.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both the `sys.path` and the `$PYTHONPATH` solutions, but they didn't seem to work. 
I didn't try adding PythonPath to `httpd.conf` or `python.conf` - that could have worked.

I ended up asking a root user to run `# python setup.py install` for me. That worked.

I was using Python 2.3.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it's the problem with setting correct `sys.path` while running from shell vs from web server.

More about `sys.path` here: [sys module](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path).

I'd recomend to try adding `~/httpdocs/python-libraries/feedparser-4.1/` (best using full path, without `~/`) to your sys.path before the import.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/httpdocs/python-libraries/feedparser-4.1/')
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
try:
    import feedparser
except:
    print "Cannot import feedparser.\n"
```

Oh, and by the way, the `httpdocs` seems like a document root for your web server. Is it the best idea to put the library there? (well, unless there's the only place you can use...)

---

edit (as a general note)

It's best to avoid the syntax like:

```
try:
  something
except:
  print "error"
```

This gives you absolutly no information about the actual error you encounter. You can assume that if you try to import a module, you have `ImportError` there, but can't be sure.

This makes debugging a real hell. Been there, done that, have lost dozens of hours due to this :)

Whenever you can, try catching one exception type at a time. So:

```
try:
  import SomeModule
except ImportError:
  print "SomeModule can't be imported"
```

You can also get familiar with the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module. It's in the standard library and it's there so you can use it. So, your exception handling code could be something like this:

```
sys.path.append('/home/user/httpdocs/python-libraries/feedparser-4.1/')
try:
  import feedparser
except ImportError:
  print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n" # text/plain so we get the stacktrace printed well
  import traceback
  import sys
  traceback.print_exc(sys.stdout) # default is sys.stderr, which is error log in case of web server running your script, we want it on standart output
  sys.exit(1)
# here goes your code to execute when all is ok, including:
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
```

Comment: Awesome tip about the traceback module. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a PYTHONPATH problem. Try changing the code to this and see what happens:

```
import sys
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
try:
    print sys.path
    import feedparser
except:
    print "Cannot import feedparser.\n"
    print sys.path
```

This probably will show that your ~/httpdocs/python-libraries/ directory is not in the path and you will need to either change sys.path or arrage for a PYTHONPATH environment variable, to correct the problem.

When you change the path, make sure that you use the full directory name, not the ~ shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than catching the exception yourself, use the [cgitb](http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html) module just once at the top of your program, and you'll get better information about all errors.

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
```